# How do you tell which field SQL 2k5 BCP is complaining about in a failed import?

Tags: sql-server, import, bcp

I am getting the error `Error - [Microsoft][SQL Native Client] String data, right truncation` about 10 times before the import fails out on the outpu log.  The error is a bit ambigous to which field in which it is related.  Normaly this wouldnt' be a problem if the dataset was in truly in 3rd normal form.  However, the dataset has over 125+ fields with over 100,000 records as a tab delimited txt file.  In this case, it will be quite an undertaking to find the offending data.  **How do you tell which field SQL 2k5 BCP is complaining about in a failed import?**  If I could find out which field is erroring out, this will greatly help narrow down the problem.

```
bcp db.dbo.table in "dataset.txt" -f "fmt.table.txt" -S instancename -U user -P password -o log.txt
```

Yes, theres a bigger story, but am limmiting it to this specific problem for simplicity sake. Otherwise going further will require another question to be asked. :)

Comment: This depends on the data, the detination table and the command run. 
Could you add the bcp command to the question? Are you using a format file? 
Its a string column. Look at the data for wider columns. Does it fail on the first row (after any header)? Look for the shortest column widths in the table. 
Bulk copy ignores the first 10 errors before failing so it would likely effect many more rows.

Comment: So I have to open the scope problem.  These were system generated (an AIX financial processing system) scripts and data files to be loaded into SQL Server.  It provided all the create table, constraints, and keys through a series of T-SQL scripts.  The data files do not contain headers, but a format file is included.  It also provided all the BCP commands to copy the information in the DB.   The bigger problem is that is should have worked seamlessly, but didn't.  `bcp db.dbo.table in "dataset.txt" -f "fmt.table.txt" -S instancename -U user -P password -o log.txt`

Comment: A lot of the info is in the format file. Please paste the file and a sample of the data (just a few rows, hash out any sensitive data).

Comment: Given the answer I provide below, is there a way to bcp or sql to treat `""` as zero-length string?  The format file for the offending field is `112 SQLCHAR 0 1 "\t" 112 CREDITREPORTADDRINDICATOR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty collation to the format file. i.e.

```
112 SQLCHAR 0 1 "\t" 112 CREDITREPORTADDRINDICATOR   ""
```

I import files with nothing between the row terminators to get null. 
Make sure consecutive tabs are included.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was found on the 112th field where the field was defined as char(1) and where the data that was extracted was literally "" giving a length of 2 all the way down each record.  I did this by importing the data as tab-delimited file into Excel setting each field as text (crucial given that Excel automatically converts date fields to a numeric value) and set the text qualifier from " to none (another conversion feature Excel does) and set it to sheet 1.  I check the field length of every datum in the dataset on the second sheet using `=len(Sheet1!A1)`, `=len(Sheet1!A2)`, `=len(Sheet1!A3)`, etc (thank god for auto fill) and pasted the shema information on the third sheet to compare the max length of each field  `=max(Sheet2!A1:A126324)`.  The base problem lies in the way the data was extracted.

This is how I did it, but I get the feeling this is far from a good way of doing it....